# Ajax - change a HTML tag within $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my HTML tag:

```
<a href="#" class="btn-delete" title="Disable group" id="{{group.id}}"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></a>
```

I use the "id" of my tag by this:

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-delete',function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

But I want to change the <\i> class which is within <\a>

Something like this:

```
$(this).find('select[class="fa fa-ban"]').removeClass().addClass("fa fa-check-circle");
```

Could you please give me a solution about how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: try to use `$(this).find('[class="fa fa-ban"]').removeClass().addClass("fa fa-check-circle");`

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(this).find('.fa-ban')
            .removeClass('fa-ban')
            .addClass('fa-check-circle');
```

Comment: Confirmed working with a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/X2bh7/1/.  However, the example code in the question had a couple of syntax errors.

Comment: At which point does it fail? Try setting some breakpoints inside the event handler and stepping through the code to see what's happening - then maybe update the question if you discover anything?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have in your code is the Context used. `this` won't be reference of a `button` or the `a` tag clicked, but it will be the `body` tag instead. because you set a listener on the `body` tag. you should change this :

```
$('body').on('click','.btn-delete',function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

to this

```
$('a').on('click','.btn-delete',function(){
var id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: This is incorrect, the 2nd parameter of the .on() function is telling jQuery what to attach to click event handler to.  The use of $('body').on(...) is the equivalent of .live() which has been depreciated.

Comment: Does this solve "$(this).find('select[class="fa fa-ban"]')...." problem? I mean the "find" is okay?

Comment: I don't think that's the case. jQuery will invoke the event handler in the context of the event's target, regardless of whether or not the target is the same element as the one to which you attached the event.